# How to specify coordinated of legend box using Show and Epilog functions?

Tags: plotting, graphics, legending, coordinate

I am trying to place the legend box using epilog function. I'm unsure where I can specify the coordinated in the sample code to specify the position.

```
Show[Plotww, Plotxx, Plotyy, Plotzz,
     Epilog -> 
      Inset[Framed[
        LineLegend[{Red, Blue, Gray, Green}, {"ww", "xx", 
          "yy", "zz"}]]]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the second argument of `Inset` to specify the position:

```
pos = {4, .5};
{plotxx, plotyy, plotww, plotzz} = {Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Red], 
   Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Blue], 
   Plot[ Cos[2 x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Gray], 
   Plot[ Sin[ 2 x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Green]};

Show[plotxx, plotyy, plotww, plotzz, 
 Epilog -> Inset[Framed[LineLegend[{Red, Blue, Gray, Green}, {"ww", "xx", "yy", "zz"}]], 
    pos]]
```

[image]