# PlotLegend assigns different sizes for plots

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have two curves that I wanted to plot where each curve is composed of two functions. As an example, the first curve is the piecewise function $\rm{sin(x)}$ for $x \in [0,5]$ and $(x-5)+\rm{sin}(5)$ for $x \in [5,10]$.

My issue is when plotting it, the `PlotLegend` assigns a shorter line on the first curve (solid line) as opposed to the second curve (dashed line). How to fix this?

In addition, is there a way to place the legend inside the plot, in the lower right corner? It's better if there is a way to input coordinates for the position, say $(8,-2)$, so that it's easily adjustable.

```
p1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 5}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 20], PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[thickness]}, PlotPoints -> 500, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-3, 3}}, PlotLegends -> Placed[{"Sin(x)"}, Right], AspectRatio -> 3/4, ImageSize -> Large];
p2 = Plot[(x - 5) + Sin[5], {x, 5, 10}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 20], PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[thickness]}, PlotPoints -> 500, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-3, 3}}, AspectRatio -> 3/4, ImageSize -> Large];
p3 = Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 5}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 20], PlotStyle -> {Black, Dashed, Thickness[thickness]}, PlotPoints -> 500, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-3, 3}}, PlotLegends -> Placed[{"Cos(x)"}, Right], AspectRatio -> 3/4, ImageSize -> Large];
p4 = Plot[(x - 5) + Cos[5], {x, 5, 10}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 20], PlotStyle -> {Black, Dashed, Thickness[thickness]}, PlotPoints -> 500, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-3, 3}}, AspectRatio -> 3/4, ImageSize -> Large];
Show[p1, p2, p3, p4]
```

[image]

Comment: Try e.g.: `PlotLegends -> Placed[{"Sin(x)"}, Scaled[{0.8, 0.1}]]`

Comment: @DanielHuber The positioning worked but the length of the legends are still not the same, the solid line is shorter than the dashed line.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not know how to change this automatism.

Comment: Without `PlotStyle->...Dashed..` there is no difference in the length of margins.

Comment: `PlotLegends -> 
 Placed[LineLegend[{Directive[{Black, Dashed}]}, {"Cos[x]"}, 
   LegendMarkerSize -> 20], Right]` and make the same change to the other entry, removing the `Dashed` directive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The different lengths of lines in the legend is indeed weird – one might even consider this as a bug.

The problem is most easily solved if you use one `Plot` instead of combining many of them with `Show` (which seems to be the cause of troubles). Furthermore, you can use [`Piecewise`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) to construct your functions.

For better clarity, I have removed options that are not part of the problem. Also, relative positioning of the legend can be done with [`Placed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Placed.html), if you want to provide absolute coordinates, use [`Inset`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/208008/75628).

```
f1 = Piecewise[{{Sin[x], 0 <= x <= 5}, {Sin[5] + (x - 5), 5 < x <= 10}}];
f2 = Piecewise[{{Cos[x], 0 <= x <= 5}, {Cos[5] + (x - 5), 5 < x <= 10}}];

Plot[{f1, f2}, {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Black, {Black, Dashed}}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"sin(x)", "cos(x)"}, {.2, .8}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

Alternatively, for a fuller description of the curves in the legend, use [`ConditionalExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression.html)

```
Plot[{
  ConditionalExpression[Sin[x], 0 <= x <= 5],
  ConditionalExpression[(x - 5) + Sin[5], 5 < x <= 10],
  ConditionalExpression[Cos[x], 0 <= x <= 5],
  ConditionalExpression[(x - 5) + Cos[5], 5 < x <= 10]},
 {x, 0, 10},
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {.325, .7}]]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** For dashed lines

```
With[{cd = ColorData[97]},
 Plot[{
   ConditionalExpression[Sin[x], 0 <= x <= 5],
   ConditionalExpression[(x - 5) + Sin[5], 5 < x <= 10],
   ConditionalExpression[Cos[x], 0 <= x <= 5],
   ConditionalExpression[(x - 5) + Cos[5], 5 < x <= 10]},
  {x, 0, 10},
  PlotStyle -> {cd[1], cd[2], {cd[3], Dashed}, {cd[4], Dashed}},
  PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {.325, .7}]]]
```

[image]